# Getting the latest java version on aws ec2

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, installation

I successfully - according to the output - "installed" java 1.8.0 on my ec2 instance using:

yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel

However I get the following:

## java -version

java version "1.7.0_141"

## javac -version

javac 1.8.0_131

Obviously I would like both to reflect the same version.

I'm not familiar with using /etc/alternatives (/java) - how to I set it so that both point to 1.8.0?

Regards

Colin Goldberg

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer - please let me know if this not all I need.

I erased java 1.7.0
ie.

## yum erase java-1.7.0-openjdk

Subsequently, I get:

## java -version

openjdk version "1.8.0_131"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)

Thanks for reading.

Colin Goldberg